# Protractor not waiting for login redirect before continuing tests in AngularJS, any suggestion?

Tags: authentication, wait, angular-ui-router, protractor

I have a standard username/password/submit button form, when the user clicks on the button the form submits with `ng-submit="login.submit()"` which does the login and on success redirects to the main page using ui.router (`$state.go("main")`).

The following test fails:

```
  describe("login", function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
      var email = element(by.model("login.email"));
      email.clear().sendKeys("mail");

      var password =  element(by.model("login.password"));
      password.clear().sendKeys("pass");

      var submit = element(by.id("submit"));
      submit.click();
    });

    it("should be able to login", function() {
      expect(element(by.css(".loginPage")).isPresent()).toBe(false);
      expect(element(by.css(".mainPage")).isPresent()).toBe(true);
    });
  });
```

and if I try to add wait times around, I can see that the browser stays on the login page the whole time (after clicking on the button) - then I get a timeout.

After a successful login the browser receives a cookie with a token for authenticating each following request.

EDIT: with some tinkering I found out where it fails..

```
function login(email, pass) {
  alert("it gets here");
  return _auth.post({ username: email, password: pass }).then(function(data) {
    alert("does not get here");
    console.log("loginok, token:" +$browser.cookies().apiToken); //this should be the received token
    return data;
  });
}
```

EDIT2: the Auth service

```
var _auth = Restangular.withConfig(function(Configurer) {
  Configurer.setBaseUrl("/");
}).service("auth/simple");

return {
  login: login,
};

function login(email, pass) {
  return _auth.post({ username: email, password: pass });
}
```

Manually everything works as expected.

Comment: This could be due to the timing issue! Not sure if this would work but did you try using a browser.sleep(1000); after the submit.click(); ?

Comment: Yes, an din any case it should automatically wait in the `beforeEach` block.. if I add a sleep after the click it simply stays on the login page for 1 second and then fails.. it is not changing state as it should.

Comment: actually it might have to do with restangular.. see edit

Comment: Just to confirm - is this working when you test it manually? Or is log-in never completing in that case? It's unclear where the code in your 'edit' is from.

Comment: edited again - yes, manually everything works. the code in the first edit is in a controller (login is called by the form submit), which uses an Auth service based on restangular (added on second edit). seems like protractor is ignoring the restangular.post

Answer (score 4):

@JoMendez's answer was very close but didn't work in my case. Used @DaveGray's [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38208494/1678614).

Had to wrap the `isPresent()` call in a function.

```js
browser.wait(function() {
  return element(by.css('.mainPage')).isPresent();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
it("should be able to login", function() {

  browser.wait(element(by.css(".mainPage")).isPresent);//this is different from sleep, this will stop the excecution of all the protractor code that is after it, until the element is present, but it won't prevent the application of loading or if is redirecting, it will keep working.

  expect(element(by.css(".loginPage")).isPresent()).toBe(false);
  expect(element(by.css(".mainPage")).isPresent()).toBe(true);
});
```

});