# Failed: Cannot read property 'getWebElements' of undefined

Tags: javascript, promise, protractor

I am new to protractor test. it seems getWebelement is missing. the version of my protector is 3.0.0. another properties are fine (such as click, evaluate ...)

```
browser.wait(element(by.id('some-element')).getWebElement);
```

or

```
browser.wait(element(by.id('some-element')).isPresent);
```

(c:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\element.js:754:36)
        at c:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\webdriver.js:720:12
        at goog.async.run.processWorkQueue (c:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\async\run.js:124:15)
        at process._tickCallback (node.js:368:9)
    From: Task: 
        at new wrappedCtr (c:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\base.js:2468:26)
        at goog.async.run.processWorkQueue (c:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\async\run.js:124:15)
        at process._tickCallback (node.js:368:9)
    From: Task: 
        at [object Object].webdriver.WebDriver.wait (c:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\webdriver.js:716:21)
        at [object Object].to.(anonymous function) [as wait] (c:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\protractor.js:65:25)
        at Object. (c:\Users\xxx\WebstormProjects\pt\spec.js:45:21)
        at c:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:96:23
        at new wrappedCtr (c:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\base.js:2468:26)
        at controlFlowExecute (c:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:82:18)
    From: Task: Run it("unknown") in control flow
        at Object. (c:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:81:14)
        at attemptAsync (c:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasmine\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:1819:24)
        at QueueRunner.run (c:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasmine\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:1774:9)
        at QueueRunner.execute (c:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasmine\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:1762:10)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
browser.wait(element(by.id('some-element')).isPresent());
```

you are missing the parenthesis after isPresent...

and after getWebElement...

```
browser.wait(element(by.id('some-element')).getWebElement());
```

Comment: The missing parens are not an error, it's correct to pass in the function itself, instead of what the function call returns. That way `browser.wait` can call the function multiple times and get potentially different results. See http://docsplendid.com/tags/wait-for-element for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to wrap the call to `isPresent()` in a function, like so:

```
browser.wait(function() {
  return element(by.id('some-element')).isPresent();
})
```

so that `isPresent()` runs each time `browser.wait` calls it.